# How do I reference elements from other resources?

Tags: reference, resources, hl7, hl7-fhir

I am currently working on XML using certain FHIR resource. It is found that certain element of the resource cross reference other resources.

e.g. In Encounter (Resource), the element :serviceProvider cross reference Resource(Organization).

In such case, is there any way to specify the elements of Resource(Organization) on Encounter (Resource) XML such that it can be validated correctly?

Comment: I'm not really sure what you are asking. What kind of validation do you want?

Comment: Perhaps you could define `validated correctly`.

Answer (score 1):

I *think* what you're asking is: Can I constrain what information care to have captured about the Organization associated with an Encounter (as opposed to an Organization communicated in some other manner or context).  For example, for an encounter, you might just want the name and phone number while in other contexts you may want other information.

If that's indeed what you're looking for,, the solution is Profile.  You would create a Profile on Encounter and, for the serviceProvider reference to Organization, on the "type" element, in addition to a "code" element indicating "Organization", you'd also specify a "profile" element pointing to a structure that you wanted to be enforced on the content of Organization.  That structure might be defined in the same profile or in a separate one.

(Note that best practice is to enforce what elements must be present but not to prevent unneeded elements from being present as doing so reduces interoperability.)